# Sync files between two compute engine instances with internal IPs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm working on GCP project in which, I have numerous small files on instance-A and I need to transfer them to instance-B. The transfer is working fine over Rsync with external IP. Both not working when I try to use internal Ip.

How can I sync files between my 2 instances with internal IPs?

Help me, please!

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Are you doing this to backup files to a replica? If so, then using disk snapshots may be easiest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if you are unable to access via ssh from "instance-A" to instance-B using the internal IP of "instance-B" because of a "Permission denied (publickey)" error.

From instance A, run:

ssh [user]@[internal IP of instance B]

If this is the case, you can generate new keys with ssh-keygen:

ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/[key file name] -C [user]

And add them to metadata.

Once done, check if you are able to ssh the instance using the internal IP. I was able to login successfully and also synced two directories using the rsync command with the internal IP.

rsync -v -e ssh ~/[source dir]/* [user]@[internal IP of instance B]:~/[destination dir]

Comment: Hi @cryotek, can you take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49942700/7644562 please?

Comment: Hi Abdul,
Unfortunately ML is not my area of expertise. Also I see some people are already assisting you on that question.